# Custom _app.tsx in NextJS is not being used, although it is in correct location

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with customizing NextJS - I have opted for using **src** folder, so my Pages are actually in `src/pages` and do work correctly. I have later added _app.tsx file as I want to use shared state with following path: `src/pages/_app.tsx` with following code:

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    debugger
    console.log('here')
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Neither the debugger nor the log are fired. I have tried to delete the .node folder and restarting the server with no change in the behavior.

[image]

Comment: Can you delete your `.next` directory in your project and try again?

Comment: I have already tried that and restarted the server again, @RobinThomas

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your project structure with all files and folders expanded?

Comment: I have added the structure, @RobinThomas

Comment: Can you rename you `app` folder to something else, and restart and see whether its working? Because you shouldn't be using both `app` and `pages` together.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot! Do you want to write the answer, @RobinThomas

Comment: if you rename the app folder, then how is next.js supposed to find the page.tsx file?

Comment: nevermind, this is the old structure and is replaced by App Router, I assumed they could be combined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because you have both `app` and `pages` together. For Next.js, you can use only one of these.

`app` router is the latest and recommended way to build Next.js apps.

> For new applications, we recommend using the App Router. For existing applications, you can incrementally migrate to the App Router.
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app

Since you already have the `app` structure, the `pages/_app.tsx` will be ignored.